# GLPaint iPhone, How to set transparent instead use color to draw on screen?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, screen, draw

Now, I plant to build application for multilayer, so I chose GLPaint demo for my application.

Example: I had 2 layer white and black, the white layer in on the top of black layer. 
          so I want to use my finger draw on white screen to make it transparent so I will be see the black layer.

so how to solve this problem with GLPaint? or other method to solve this problem?